# Excel over 100% then = 100%

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-statements

I am calculating percentage and currently I have cells with the formula

```
=IF($H4="3PL",L4/Data!B$24,L4/Data!B$21)
```

I need to add a second piece: If the answer of above is greater than 100% make it equal 100% and not higher

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use min:

```
=MIN(IF($H4="3PL",L4/Data!B$24,L4/Data!B$21),100%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not trying, just crossing in my mind...

```
=IF($H4="3PL",IF(L4/Data!B$24 >= 100, 100, L4/Data!B$24), IF(L4/Data!B$21 >= 100, 100, L4/Data!B$21))
```

Hope it is useful...

Comment: Arrghhh!!  This is so much more complicated than the other answer!